How do i use IPTables to forward a port to a different local ip when using DMZ
My router software is garbage, it only allows forwarding certain ports, luckly i found out that DMZ works, i have a linux server, can i point DMZ to that linux server and just use it to forward ports to for example an RDP?
If yes, how do I do that?

Please do some search to understand what DMZ is in the context of a router. Once you know then hopefully you'll understand why asking about port forwarding makes no sense.

from what i understood, DMZ makes it so all ports get forwarded to a ip that i choose instead of all of them being closed and only certain ones gets forwared, the thing is my router does not allow ports like 22, and a few others, i use DMZ to be able to use port 22 as it opens all ports, but i do want to forward all traffic from port 17006 for example to a windows server so basically my linux server which DMZ is pointing to forwards it to the windows server, is what i understood wrong?

It might work, but you'll probably need to make the windows server use the linux server as its default gateway (to allow "reverse SNAT" to be applied to the replying traffics), or SNAT (MASQUERADE) (in addition to DNAT'ing) the "redirected" incoming traffics in the first place (but then on the windows server, all the requests would been seen as originated from the linux server).

That is a good idea, it is a simple vmware vm (the windows box) so i am guessing its possible?
